# Find $\int_0^{2\pi} \log|1-re^{i\theta}| d\theta$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a homework problem and it asks to find 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log|1-re^{i\theta}| d\theta$$
when $0\leq r<1$, $r=1$, and $r>1$. I understand that for $0\leq r<1$, $\log |1-re^{i\theta}|$ is harmonic since it can be regarded as the real part of $\log(1-z)$, but how should I deal with $r=1$ and $r>1$?

Comment: For $r > 1$, start with rewriting $\lvert 1 - r e^{i\theta}\rvert = r\cdot \lvert e^{i\theta} - r^{-1}\rvert$. Can you see how to continue? For $r = 1$, you could look at the limit $r\to 1^-$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't find a good reference for this [mean value property for harmonic functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mean-ValueProperty.html)

Comment: @DanielFischer I wanted  something like $\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+r e^{it} )dt=\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+R e^{it}) dt$ if $f(z)$ is harmonic on $|r|\le |a-z| \le |R|$

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I see the case for $r>1$. For $r=1$, how can I pull the limit out of the integral?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I see since the integral is not over $r$.

Comment: That depends on what you have to work with. The dominated convergence theorem is one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<r<1$
$$\log\left|1-r e^{i\theta}\right| = \text{Re}\log(1-re^{i\theta})=-\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{r^n e^{ni\theta}}{n}=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{r^n\cos(n\theta)}{n}\tag{1}$$
implies that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log\left|1-r e^{i\theta}\right|\,d\theta=0.$ The same holds if $r=1$, although we have to be careful in performing the same manipulation (better to perform summation/integration by parts, for starters). If $r>1$,
$$ \log\left|1-r e^{i\theta}\right| = \log (r)+\text{Re}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{r}\right) \tag{2}$$
so $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log\left|1-r e^{i\theta}\right|\,d\theta=2\pi\log(r).$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{1 - r\expo{\ic\theta}}}\,\dd\theta =
\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{1 - r\expo{\ic\theta}}\,\dd\theta =
\Re\oint_{\verts{z} = r}\,\,\,\ln\pars{1 - z}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\oint_{\verts{z} = r}{\ln\pars{1 - z} \over z}\,\dd z
\end{align}

---

1. $\ds{\large{r < 1}:\ ?}$.

   Obviously, the integral $\underline{\textsf{vanishes out}}$ because there isn't any pole inside the contour:
   $$\bbx{\ds{%
   \left.\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{1 - r\expo{\ic\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
   \,\right\vert_{\ r\ <\ 1}\ =\ 0}}
   $$

   ---
2. $\ds{\large{r > 1}:\ ?}$.

   In this case we must set a $\ds{\ln\pars{1 - z}}$*-branch cut* as follows:
   $$
   \ln\pars{1 - z} = \ln\pars{\verts{1 - z}} + \,\mrm{arg}\pars{1 - z}\ic\,,\qquad
   0 < \,\mrm{arg}\pars{1 - z} < 2\pi\,,\qquad z \not= 1
   $$
   Namely,
   \begin{align}
   &\left.\Im\oint_{\verts{z} = r}{\ln\pars{1 - z} \over z}\,\dd z
   \,\right\vert_{\ r\ >\ 1} =
   \Im\pars{-\int_{r}^{1}{\ln\pars{x - 1} + 2\pi\ic \over x}\,\dd x -
   \int_{1}^{r}{\ln\pars{x - 1} + 0\ic \over x}\,\dd x}
   \\[5mm] = &
   \Im\pars{-2\pi\ic\int_{r}^{1}{\dd x \over x}} = \bbx{\ds{2\pi\ln\pars{r}}}
   \end{align}

   ---

   $$
   \bbox[15px,#ffe,border:2px dotted navy]{\ds{%
   \int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{1 - r\expo{\ic\theta}}}\,\dd\theta =
   2\pi\,\Theta\pars{r - 1}\ln\pars{r}}}
   $$

   > $\ds{\Theta}$ is the *Heaviside Step Function*.